# Difference in abbreviated month name in Python across machines

Tags: python, datetime, locale, abbreviation

I'm trying to parse german dates in the form of `%d. %b. %Y`.
Using the same locale, I get different abbreviations for `März` (month march).

When I run:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
loc = locale.getlocale()
print("changed locale " + str(loc))
print(datetime(2020, 3, 19).strftime("%b"))
```

On Windows 10, Python `3.7.2` it prints:

> changed locale ('de_DE', 'ISO8859-1') 
>   Mrz

However, the cloud function (also python `3.7`) prints

> changed locale ('de_DE', 'ISO8859-1')
>   Mär

How can it be that `März` is once abbreviated `Mär` and on another machine `Mrz` and how can is be resolved?
Is there another locale to be used?

Comment: FWIW, `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` gives me an `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`, but `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german_germany')` works and prints `changed locale ('de_DE', 'cp1252')` and `Mrz`. (using both Python 2.7.17 and Python 3.8.1 on a Windows machine)

Comment: It appears that the German abbreviation of `März` **is** `März` — so neither is correct.

Comment: @martineau I don't know where you got that from, but `März` is not a short form. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4rz

Comment: Ich spreche kein deutsch — seemed to be the case from several sources I looked at. Regardless, the first line of the German Wikipedia article says "Der März (Abkürzung Mrz. oder Mär.[1])" which partially translated into English is "March (abbreviation Mrz. or Mär. [1])", so the answer is either way is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I foudn a workaround on [Python-Forum.de](https://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=39873#p304279).

The idea is to create a custom parser, which works quite well for my case:

```
class GermanParserInfo(parser.parserinfo):
    MONTHS = [
        ('Jan', 'Januar'),
        ('Feb', 'Februar'),
        ('Mär', 'Mrz', 'März'),
        ('Apr', 'April'),
        ('Mai',),
        ('Jun', 'Juni'),
        ('Jul', 'Juli'),
        ('Aug', 'August'),
        ('Sep', 'Sept', 'September'),
        ('Okt', 'Oktober'),
        ('Nov', 'November'),
        ('Dez', 'Dezember'),
    ]

date = parser.parse(input, GermanParserInfo())
```